# How do I get customer info on successpage for third party service

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

I have a third party service that needs customer info to manage advertisement.
I have this code for the successpage of Magento:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> window.sovIframes = window.sovIframes || []; window.sovIframes.push({ 

trafficSourceNumber : '3637',
trafficMediumNumber : '2',
sessionId : 'Session-ID',
timestamp : 'Timestamp',
orderId : 'Order-ID',
orderValue : 'Bestelwaarde',
orderCurrency : 'Bestelvaluta',
usedCouponCode : 'Gebruikte kortingscode',
iframeContainerId : 'sovendus-container-1' });
```

The values between the brackets must be the values of Magento.
How do I get these values? Are they loaded on the successpage automatically?

Comment: are you need login customer data or order data?

Comment: Actually I need both: order data and customer data

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer(); ?>
<?php $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getOrderId());?>

<?php if($order && $order->getId()):?>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.sovIframes = window.sovIframes || []; window.sovIframes.push({ 

orderId : '<?php echo $order->getIncrementId();?>',
orderValue : '<?php echo number_format($order->getGrandTotal(), 2)?>',
orderCurrency : '<?php echo $order->getBaseCurrencyCode();?>',
}); 

</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

**Note:** I have added order data in above code. You are used same way customer data. for eg. `sessionId : '<?php echo $customer->getEmail();?>`'

Comment: Thanks, The if-statement prevents the javascript from being executed. can there be a problem in that? `<?php if($order && $order->getId()):?>`